# Global Variable Error in Python List

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I am working on a function that would take an user's input for four people's names and to append them to a list. However with the code below I get this user error. However, when I declare significant_other as a global variable, I get an invalid syntax error. How would I fix my code?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mash.py", line 16, in <module>
    print spouse()
  File "mash.py", line 13, in spouse
    significant_other = signficant_other.append(new_spouse)
NameError: global name 'signficant_other' is not defined
```

Here is the code.

```
import random
# import random module


def spouse():
# defined function
    significant_other =[]
    #empty list
    for x in range(4):
    # for loop for an iteration of four
        new_spouse = str(raw_input("Type a person you would like to spend your life with."))
        # new spouse input
        significant_other = signficant_other.append(new_spouse)
        #significant other gets added to the list

print spouse()
```

Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your line:

```
significant_other = signficant_other.append(new_spouse)
```

To this:

```
significant_other.append(new_spouse)
```

Basically you cannot assign a append method because it by default returns `None`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a.append(5)
>>> print b
None
```

And so if you change your code to `signficant_other.append(new_spouse)` It still fails because you made a small typo you've spelled `significant` as `signficant`

Answer (score 2):

You spelt `significant_other` like this `signficant_other`

plus you just need to do:

```
significant_other.append(new_spouse)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, firstly:

```
significant_other = signficant_other.append(new_spouse)
```

`.append()` will **not** return a list, it modifies the list and returns `None`.

Secondly, you're attempting to use `print`, but the function that you're calling doesn't return what you want, it returns `None`.

Additionally, there was a spelling issue, but the above two are more important.

Try this:

```
def spouse():

    significant_other = []

    for x in range(4):

        new_spouse = str(raw_input("...."))
        significant_other.append(new_spouse)

    return significant_other

print spouse()
```